# class selector in css

Tags: css

i am working with bootstrap and i am confused with it css. They have class selector in their css code. i dont understand what this code actually does. Does this css apply on only span or what else.

```
.row-fluid [class*="span"] {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 28px;
  margin-left: 2.127659574%;
  *margin-left: 2.0744680846382977%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: You can lookup what selectors do for example at jQuery's site: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a partial attribute selctor, and applies to anything with the string `span` in it's class name. It's used for `span2` and such. For example `[class*="span"]` will match these elements:

```
<p class="span"></p>
<p class="spanner"></p>
<p class="espanol"></p>
<p class="span43 blue"></p>
```

Comment: That will only match an element with *exactly* `class="span"`. Here's are two references for attribute selectors: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors, http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/css3attributeselectors

Comment: but it this method support all the browser

Comment: Worth noting that this type of selector is rather buggy in <IE9. However, this particular case (using the `class` attribute in the selector) this strangely [does work in both IE7 and IE8](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/css3attributeselectors). Just thought I'd point that out as you have the ole IE7 asterick hack in your CSS, insinuating that you are aiming for IE7 compatibility.

Comment: I would use `*=` as sparingly as possible in all cases personally. It's much too broad and easy to make mistakes with. @MusikAnimal: I'm not certain what the browser support is but this is not the asterisk hack, it's a valid selector, added in CSS3.

Comment: @WesleyMurch By asterisk hack I was referring to the line `*margin-left: 2.0744680846382977%;` in his CSS

Comment: @MusikAnimal: Oh I see, my mistake. The OP's CSS is from the Twitter Bootstrap framework, I guess they use IE hacks.

Comment: .jit + .vit what is the effect of this kind of css